# Google Maps API - want to cycle through and get directions for points in KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directions

I've got a program which generates KML files, and now want to cycle through the placemarks in order to find the nearest one. But I'm having a problem cycling through them.

Basically, I parse the KML into a Google Earth plugin. Clicking on one of the placemarks in the Google Earth plugin gets it's lat/lon (as StartLat and StartLon) and starts up this code:

```
function GetDir()
{
  var PlaceMarks=ge.getElementsByType('KmlPlacemark');
  i=0;
  GetNext=1;
  while(i<3)
  {
    if(GetNext==1)
    {
      GetNext=0;
      var PM2 = PlaceMarks.item(i);
      var request=
      {
        origin: StartLat + ", " + StartLon,
        destination: PM2.getGeometry().getLatitude() + ", " + PM2.getGeometry().getLongitude(),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status)
      {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
          directionDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I've got an "idle" listener on the map so, theoretically, after it's found the directions and displayed them, i is incremented by 1, so we move to the next placemark, and GetNext is set to 1, so we call the directions again.

At the moment it snarls up and IE8 (the only browser our IT dept will let us use) says that the script is running slowly. I've got the feeling that, using this loop, it can't listen for a response.

EDIT - sorry, should have mentioned, there's also a map on the same page that shows the result. It does work when dealing with only one (outside of this loop), whilst at the moment this loop only deals with three (hence the while(i<3)). The intention is for this to deal with lots of placemarks, and I can get the amount of placemarks in a KML file no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Instead of incrementing everything on the Idle listener, I instead made the Idle listener call the procedure which moved to the next point. Relevant code:

This puts the KML file into the Google Earth API, and attaches the code to start cycling through:

```
function GetKML()
{
  if (currentKmlObject)
    ge.getFeatures().removeChild(currentKmlObject);
  var KmlBox = document.getElementById('kml-box');
  var KmlString = KmlBox.value;
  try
  {
    currentKmlObject=ge.parseKml(KmlString);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(currentKmlObject);
    google.earth.addEventListener(currentKmlObject, 'click', function(event)
    {
      var placemark = event.getTarget();
      StartLat = placemark.getGeometry().getLatitude();
      StartLon = placemark.getGeometry().getLongitude();
      alert('Start point set. Latitude: ' + StartLat + ' Longitude: ' + StartLon + '. Finding nearest...');
      AreWeSearching=1;
      i=0;
      GetDir();
    });
    var PlaceMarks=ge.getElementsByType('KmlPlacemark');
    KMLLength=PlaceMarks.getLength();
    alert('KML parsed and added. ' + KMLLength + ' points available. Please click which placemark you would like as your START point on the EARTH screen.');
  }
  catch(ex)
  {
    alert('Parse error');
  }
}
```

This is the code for the GetDir function which interrogates the placemarks. At the moment this only goes up to 10, but I'll just use the PlaceMarks length:

```
function GetDir()
{
  if(i==10){AreWeSearching=0;}
  if(AreWeSearching==1)
  {
    var PlaceMarks=ge.getElementsByType('KmlPlacemark');
    var PM2 = PlaceMarks.item(i);
    var request=
    {
      origin: StartLat + ", " + StartLon,
      destination: PM2.getGeometry().getLatitude() + ", " + PM2.getGeometry().getLongitude(),
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status)
    {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
      {
        directionDisplay.setDirections(result);
      }
    });
    i=i+1;
  }
}
```

On the Maps API's idle listener it calls the GetDir function again, so essentially it's called for a first time and, whenever it is idle, gets called again, until we stop going through it.

Basically, what I'm building it for (for anyone who hasn't worked it out already) is so that I can find the nearest placemark to a placemark that I click. Using a bit of extra code it'll allow me to route my way around a KML file's placemarks, starting at a selected placemark.

So, for anyone wanting a way of routing a KML file FROM YOUR HARD DRIVE, create a page with a Google Earth plugin and a Google Maps plugin. Load the KML into Google Earth, as I've done above, then use Google Maps and the Idle listener to cycle through.